# Strange border - outline on greek characters since v1.63 VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Today I opened Visual Studio Code to continue my project and I realized that almost every Greek character has a border as it is shown in the picture.

- What is this?
- How can I disable it?

[image: An example of what I am describing above]

Answer (score 13):

These are caused by these `unicode highlighting` settings that are new to v1.63:

[image: unicode highlight options]

You can try disabling them or you can change the color with these `colorCustomizations` in your `settings.json`:

```
 "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorUnicodeHighlight.border": "#0000",  // set to transparent
    "minimap.unicodeHighlight": "#0000",
    "editorOverviewRuler.unicodeForeground": "#0000"
}
```

Comment: I just added the first two lines from above to my settings.json, and it fixed it for Hebrew.

Answer (score 0):

Replying to myself, i downgraded to 1.62.2 version and everything is back to normal.