# VSCode: Why are some Hebrew characters displayed in a box?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My version of VSCode is below.

I do mostly Powershell. Also do some text editing with a mix of Hebrew and English.
I only notice this behavior when the syntax mode of the editor is Powershell. When the mode is plain text, this oddity is not present.

The odd display behavior:

[image]

What to do?

```
Version: 1.63.2 (system setup)
Commit: 899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3
Date: 2021-12-15T09:40:02.816Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19042
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70338487/836330 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/70293571/836330

Comment: I think this should really be closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/70293571/836330.  Okay if I do so?

Comment: @Mark Maybe as a dupe that is OK. The problem presentation is a little odd. Most users who use an additional character set only use one in addition to English. Closing it as a dupe will allow a Hebrew user to find the answer, so that seems cool. (I never would have found the threads discussing Greek or Arabic.)

Comment: Yeah I am hoping that `border/box/outline around characters` and v1.63 is what leads people to the questions.  I don't really know how to edit the questions to make them more discoverable...

Answer (score 1):

The fix is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70293571/147637).

I used a subset of the answer. I added to settings.json:

```
 "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorUnicodeHighlight.border": "#0000",  // set to transparent
  }
```