# Skip whitespaces from string

Tags: javascript, c#, html, visual-studio-code

I don't know but maybe after last update of Visual Studio Code, when I copy string text from description from a task for example, its coming with all intersting whitespaces.How I can skip all whitespaces from a string in visual studio code => [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxORI.png)

Comment: Your answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70293571/3807365 - Basically it is related to Unicode funny chars being highlighted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange border - outline on greek characters since v1.63 VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70290603/strange-border-outline-on-greek-characters-since-v1-63-vs-code)

Comment: TLDR; Search for "unicode highlight" in your settings and disable it if you don't want it (but make sure, the chars are the ones you meant )

Comment: Yes, I found it, thank you! When I hold with a mouse on one of this bracket, it coming a window => 'The character U+00a0 is invisible. Adjust settings'. And when I click on 'Adjust settings' it comes other window => 'Configure Unicode Highlight Options', when there are two options => 'Exclude...' and 'Disable....'. So I choose Disable, and this bracket was in the past!